# Chinese and Japanese characters are stored as HTML codes in SQL Server database

Tags: encoding, asp-classic

I have created a webpage using Classic ASP. This page allows user to enter notes in English/Chinese/Japanese. When I store the note in SQL Server database, the Chinese and Japanese characters are stored as HTML codes, like &#28858.;&#25237.;&#36039.;&#32773.
I want them to be rendered as actual Unicode characters in database.

I have tried changing the Codepage to 65001. It doesn't work.

The SQL Server field in which notes are stored is nvarchar(max).

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Not easy to help when you are not showing your code.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be two ways around this. The first is to use paramaters for insert, updates and deletes. I think this is the recommended solution. If you really can't try using a N character before the text. Eg,

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.test_table(N'UnicodeValue')
```

[Look here for more information.](http://www.sql-questions.com/microsoft/SQL-Server/32307760/change-the-encoding-of-an-existing-db.aspx)

Comment: Hi Daniel...N character is not required here, as the note is being passed as a parameter to a stored procedure. 
Any other idea?